# how to change font size in eclipse (Mars 4.5.2 c/c++ IDE)

Tags: eclipse

Im looking for a way (and keyboard shortcut of course) to increase/decrease font size(or zoom in/zoom out of the code for that matter) .

Thanks for your help

Comment: AFAIK, the feature was introduced in 4.6 Neon. You can't do that in Mars. I've voted to close the question.

Comment: So it's a valid question, and the valid answer is "you can't". Why close it?

Answer (score 2):

There is not support for Zoom in Eclipse Mars. All you can do is set the font sizes in the Preferences in 'General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts'

Eclipse Neon (4.6) adds support for zooming text editors using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to go smaller) (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> on Macs). It also supports 'pinch zoom' if you use a trackpad.